# how to resolve "Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError"

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm creating an application in which nearby places will be shown on the map using SQLite database. When I run the code it will give **Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError** on **MainActivity.java:33**. which is `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`
I've checked my manifest then I realize that

```
`        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />`
```

this line is not added in the manifest and the targetsdk version was 8. When I add this line and change the targetsdk version to 16 it will give an error "**error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version').**" but when I change the android value to 4030500 it will run but crash. Now I don't get the point why it is crashing. Please help. Here is my Code of manifest, mainActivity.java class and log cat.

**Logcat**

```
> 05-12 00:39:10.705: D/jdwp(31381): sendBufferedRequest : len=0x6D
05-12 00:39:10.707: W/asset(31381): AssetManager-->addDefaultAssets CIP path not exsit!
05-12 00:39:10.738: D/ActivityThread(31381): installProvider: context=android.app.Application@4184c140holder=nullnoisy=falsenoReleaseNeeded=truestable=true
05-12 00:39:10.738: D/ActivityThread(31381): installProvider: context.getPackageName()=in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationmarkersqliteai.packageName=in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationmarkersqlite
05-12 00:39:10.929: W/dalvikvm(31381): VFY: unable to resolve static field 982 (MapAttrs) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$styleable;
05-12 00:39:10.929: D/dalvikvm(31381): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x000e
05-12 00:39:10.936: D/AndroidRuntime(31381): Shutting down VM
05-12 00:39:10.936: W/dalvikvm(31381): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x412899a8)
05-12 00:39:10.951: E/AndroidRuntime(31381): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-12 00:39:10.951: E/AndroidRuntime(31381): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
05-12 00:39:10.951: E/AndroidRuntime(31381):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)
05-12 00:39:10.951: E/AndroidRuntime(31381):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
05-12 00:39:10.951: E/AndroidRuntime(31381):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:279)
05-12 00:39:10.951: E/AndroidRuntime(31381):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
05-12 00:39:10.951: E/AndroidRuntime(31381):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
05-12 00:39:10.951: E/AndroidRuntime(31381):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
05-12 00:39:10.951: E/AndroidRuntime(31381):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
05-12 00:39:10.951: E/AndroidRuntime(31381):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
05-12 00:39:10.951: E/AndroidRuntime(31381):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:281)
05-12 00:39:10.951: E/AndroidRuntime(31381):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
05-12 00:39:10.951: E/AndroidRuntime(31381):    at in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationmarkersqlite.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)
05-12 00:39:10.951: E/AndroidRuntime(31381):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
05-12 00:39:10.951: E/AndroidRuntime(31381):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
05-12 00:39:10.951: E/AndroidRuntime(31381):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
05-12 00:39:10.951: E/AndroidRuntime(31381):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
05-12 00:39:10.951: E/AndroidRuntime(31381):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
05-12 00:39:10.951: E/AndroidRuntime(31381):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
05-12 00:39:10.951: E/AndroidRuntime(31381):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
05-12 00:39:10.951: E/AndroidRuntime(31381):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
05-12 00:39:10.951: E/AndroidRuntime(31381):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
05-12 00:39:10.951: E/AndroidRuntime(31381):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-12 00:39:10.951: E/AndroidRuntime(31381):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-12 00:39:10.951: E/AndroidRuntime(31381):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
05-12 00:39:10.951: E/AndroidRuntime(31381):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
05-12 00:39:10.951: E/AndroidRuntime(31381):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-12 00:39:28.242: D/jdwp(31463): sendBufferedRequest : len=0x6D
05-12 00:39:28.243: D/jdwp(31463): processIncoming
05-12 00:39:28.243: D/jdwp(31463): handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x13, id=0x400001C0, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x8
05-12 00:39:28.245: D/jdwp(31463): processIncoming
05-12 00:39:28.245: D/jdwp(31463): handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x17, id=0x400001C1, flags=0x0, dataLen=0xC
05-12 00:39:28.245: W/asset(31463): AssetManager-->addDefaultAssets CIP path not exsit!
05-12 00:39:28.246: D/jdwp(31463): processIncoming
05-12 00:39:28.246: D/jdwp(31463): handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x13, id=0x400001C2, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x8
05-12 00:39:28.246: D/jdwp(31463): processIncoming
05-12 00:39:28.247: D/jdwp(31463): handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x13, id=0x400001C3, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x8
05-12 00:39:28.253: D/ActivityThread(31463): installProvider: context=android.app.Application@4184e080holder=nullnoisy=falsenoReleaseNeeded=truestable=true
05-12 00:39:28.253: D/ActivityThread(31463): installProvider: context.getPackageName()=in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationmarkersqliteai.packageName=in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationmarkersqlite
05-12 00:39:28.316: W/dalvikvm(31463): VFY: unable to resolve static field 982 (MapAttrs) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$styleable;
05-12 00:39:28.316: D/dalvikvm(31463): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x000e
05-12 00:39:28.318: D/AndroidRuntime(31463): Shutting down VM
05-12 00:39:28.319: W/dalvikvm(31463): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x412899a8)
05-12 00:39:28.321: E/AndroidRuntime(31463): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-12 00:39:28.321: E/AndroidRuntime(31463): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
05-12 00:39:28.321: E/AndroidRuntime(31463):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)
05-12 00:39:28.321: E/AndroidRuntime(31463):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
05-12 00:39:28.321: E/AndroidRuntime(31463):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:279)
05-12 00:39:28.321: E/AndroidRuntime(31463):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
05-12 00:39:28.321: E/AndroidRuntime(31463):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
05-12 00:39:28.321: E/AndroidRuntime(31463):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
05-12 00:39:28.321: E/AndroidRuntime(31463):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
05-12 00:39:28.321: E/AndroidRuntime(31463):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
05-12 00:39:28.321: E/AndroidRuntime(31463):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:281)
05-12 00:39:28.321: E/AndroidRuntime(31463):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
05-12 00:39:28.321: E/AndroidRuntime(31463):    at in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationmarkersqlite.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)
05-12 00:39:28.321: E/AndroidRuntime(31463):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
05-12 00:39:28.321: E/AndroidRuntime(31463):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
05-12 00:39:28.321: E/AndroidRuntime(31463):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
05-12 00:39:28.321: E/AndroidRuntime(31463):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
05-12 00:39:28.321: E/AndroidRuntime(31463):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
05-12 00:39:28.321: E/AndroidRuntime(31463):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
05-12 00:39:28.321: E/AndroidRuntime(31463):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
05-12 00:39:28.321: E/AndroidRuntime(31463):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
05-12 00:39:28.321: E/AndroidRuntime(31463):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
05-12 00:39:28.321: E/AndroidRuntime(31463):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-12 00:39:28.321: E/AndroidRuntime(31463):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-12 00:39:28.321: E/AndroidRuntime(31463):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
05-12 00:39:28.321: E/AndroidRuntime(31463):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
05-12 00:39:28.321: E/AndroidRuntime(31463):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Manifest**

```
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />    

    <permission
          android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationmarkersqlite.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
          android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationmarkersqlite.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>       

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationmarkersqlite.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

         <provider 
            android:name="LocationsContentProvider"
            android:authorities="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationmarkersqlite.locations"
            android:exported="false" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyDWcQ-K232pqKKftNuiP_f-OIQ9YaqNQiM" />
        <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="4030500" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
   package in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationmarkersqlite;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks;
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Getting Google Play availability status
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

        // Showing status
        if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ // Google Play Services are not available

            int requestCode = 10;
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
            dialog.show();

        }else { // Google Play Services are available           

            // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment of activity_main.xml
            SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

            // Getting GoogleMap object from the fragment
            googleMap = fm.getMap();

            // Enabling MyLocation Layer of Google Map
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);           

            // Invoke LoaderCallbacks to retrieve and draw already saved locations in map
            getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);            
        }        

        googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {      


                // Drawing marker on the map
                drawMarker(point);          

                // Creating an instance of ContentValues
                ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

                // Setting latitude in ContentValues
                contentValues.put(LocationsDB.FIELD_LAT, point.latitude );

                // Setting longitude in ContentValues
                contentValues.put(LocationsDB.FIELD_LNG, point.longitude);

                // Setting zoom in ContentValues
                contentValues.put(LocationsDB.FIELD_ZOOM, googleMap.getCameraPosition().zoom);

                // Creating an instance of LocationInsertTask
                LocationInsertTask insertTask = new LocationInsertTask();

                // Storing the latitude, longitude and zoom level to SQLite database
                insertTask.execute(contentValues);                

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Marker is added to the Map", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                  

            }
        }); 


        googleMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new OnMapLongClickListener() {              
            @Override
            public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {

                // Removing all markers from the Google Map
                googleMap.clear();

                // Creating an instance of LocationDeleteTask
                LocationDeleteTask deleteTask = new LocationDeleteTask();

                // Deleting all the rows from SQLite database table
                deleteTask.execute();

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "All markers are removed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
    }


    private void drawMarker(LatLng point){
        // Creating an instance of MarkerOptions
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();                  

        // Setting latitude and longitude for the marker
        markerOptions.position(point);

        // Adding marker on the Google Map
        googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);         
    }


    private class LocationInsertTask extends AsyncTask<ContentValues, Void, Void>{
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(ContentValues... contentValues) {

            /** Setting up values to insert the clicked location into SQLite database */           
            getContentResolver().insert(LocationsContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, contentValues[0]);            
            return null;
        }       
    }

    private class LocationDeleteTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            /** Deleting all the locations stored in SQLite database */
            getContentResolver().delete(LocationsContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, null, null);          
            return null;
        }       
    }   


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0,
            Bundle arg1) {

        // Uri to the content provider LocationsContentProvider
        Uri uri = LocationsContentProvider.CONTENT_URI;

        // Fetches all the rows from locations table
        return new CursorLoader(this, uri, null, null, null, null);

    }


    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0,
            Cursor arg1) {
        int locationCount = 0;
        double lat=0;
        double lng=0;
        float zoom=0;

        // Number of locations available in the SQLite database table
        locationCount = arg1.getCount();

        // Move the current record pointer to the first row of the table
        arg1.moveToFirst();

        for(int i=0;i<locationCount;i++){

            // Get the latitude
            lat = arg1.getDouble(arg1.getColumnIndex(LocationsDB.FIELD_LAT));

            // Get the longitude
            lng = arg1.getDouble(arg1.getColumnIndex(LocationsDB.FIELD_LNG));

            // Get the zoom level
            zoom = arg1.getFloat(arg1.getColumnIndex(LocationsDB.FIELD_ZOOM));

            // Creating an instance of LatLng to plot the location in Google Maps
            LatLng location = new LatLng(lat, lng);

            // Drawing the marker in the Google Maps
            drawMarker(location);

            // Traverse the pointer to the next row
            arg1.moveToNext();
        }

        if(locationCount>0){
            // Moving CameraPosition to last clicked position
            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(lat,lng)));

            // Setting the zoom level in the map on last position  is clicked
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(zoom));  

        }       
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }   
}
```

http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/gps-and-google-map-in-android-applications-series/

This is the tutorial I used.

Comment: I guess you re missing Google play services. you can install it from sdk manager

Comment: Also make sure to add the library to your project once you install it.

Comment: I've added the google play services and libraries in my project. But as I debug my application google play libraries automatically removed and a red cross sign has displayed instead of a green tick.